# why the modal not close completely with codeigniter jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

please help me, my modals when edit or update(CRUD) on codeigniter with jquery not close completely,the update was success but the display is blank

this is my submit button on form

```
<button onclick='update' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModals<?php echo $data->id ; ?>" class="btn btn-warning">edit</button>
```

and this is my update modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModals<?php echo $data->id ; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">edit</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="user">username:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user<?php echo $data->id ; ?>" value="<?php echo $data->username ?>">
               </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pass<?php echo $data->id ; ?>" value="<?php echo $data->password ?>">
               </div>
              <button type="submit" onclick='update(<?= $data->id ;?>)' class="btn btn-success">update data</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my jquery script

```
function update(id){
var user = $("#user"+id).val();
var password = $("#pass"+id).val();


$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    url: "<?= site_url('ajax/update'); ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: "username="+user+"&password="+password+"&id="+id,
    }).done(function(data) {
      $("#myModals"+id).modal('hide');
      load(); 
    });
```

my controller is

```
public function update(){
$id= $this->input->post('id');
$data = array(
  'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
  'password' => $this->input->post('password')
);
$this->model_ajax->update_data('user', $data, $id);}
```

and my modal is

```
public function update_data($table, $data, $id){

$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->update($table, $data);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the data back from the controller to your script and then update the DOM.

in your controller, so something like:

```
public function update()
{
    $id= $this->input->post( 'id' );
    $data = array(
      'username' => $this->input->post( 'username' ),
      'password' => $this->input->post( 'password' )
    );
    $this->model_ajax->update_data( 'user', $data, $id );

    // return the updated data via json
    echo json_encode( $this->input->post() );
}
```

and then in your jQuery

```
function update(id){
    var user = $("#user"+id).val();
    var password = $("#pass"+id).val();


    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'html',
            url: "<?= site_url('ajax/update'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: "username="+user+"&password="+password+"&id="+id,
        })
        .done(
            function( data ) {
                $( "#myModals" + data.id ).modal( 'hide' );
                load(); 
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For closing modal you can try $("#myModals"+id).modal('toggle'); This will close the modal. Also please make sure that the ajax response is correct and you are getting the expected result.